# probability of contingency table

Tags: probability

Mary is one of Doctor Brown's patients. She has conducted a home pregnancy test which has given a positive result. What is the probability that the pregnancy test used by Doctor Brown in his surgery will say Mary is pregnant given that the home test was positive?

Home pregnancy test is $85$% accurate

Doctor Brown pregnancy test is $95$% accurate

$20$ females are pregnant and $80$ females are not

*I don't know how to add the contingency tables to this question

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you don't have enough information to solve this.  Here's how I'd approach it.

Let $X$ be the random variable which is $1$ if the home test is positive and $0$ otherwise.  Similarly let $Y=1$ if Dr. Brown's test is positive, and let $P=1$ if Mary is actually pregnant.  We want the conditional probability $Pr(Y=1\mid X=1)$.  Write

$$\begin{align}
 & Pr(Y=1\mid X=1)\\
 =\,&Pr(X=1 \wedge Y=1) / Pr(X=1)\\
 =\,&\frac{Pr(X=1 \wedge Y=1 \mid P=1)Pr(P=1) + Pr(X=1 \wedge Y=1 \mid P=0)Pr(P=0)}{
  Pr(X=1 \mid P=1)Pr(P=1) + Pr(X=1 \mid P=0)Pr(P=0).}
\end{align}$$

**If** we're willing to assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $P$, we can write $Pr(X=1 \wedge Y=1 \mid P=1)=Pr(X=1\mid P=1)\,Pr(Y=1\mid P=1).$  This may be a reasonable assumption if Dr. Brown's test works on different principles than the home test, but it might not.  Given that assumption, this gives an answer of 
$$\frac{(0.85)(0.95)(0.2) + (0.15)(0.05)(0.8)}{0.85)(0.2)+(0.15)(0.8)}\approx 0.56$$